# Fill a Grid Cell with a scaled View

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scale

I want to fill a space in a `Grid` with a `View` which got scaled down (Scale="0.5"). Assume I have a `Grid` with three rows and two columns, and the scaled down View should fill `Grid.Row="1"` `Grid.Column="1"` like this (outlined in red):

[image: achieved in a hacky way]

The problem I'm running into is that the `View` will get scaled down, but it doesn't re-position itself in the grid. The former size is still dominant for how big the cells of the grid actually is:

[image]

Seeing this result, I see two problems:

1. HorizontalOptions are not executed after the scaling happens
2. Grid Cell height is not being updated to fit the new height of the scaled view

As you can see in the first image, I achieved to scale it down and respect the `Grid` size. However, this is in a **very** hacky way by translating the `View` with hard coded values to the right position. So as soon as I add any new views to this Page, the positioning of the scaled down `View` will be wrong.

This is my (simplified) code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Other Views...-->
    <CircularView 
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.Column="0"
    </CircularView>
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Scale="0.5"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HeightRequest="240"
        IsVisible="{Binding HasTermine}">
        <MyCustomView/>
    </Grid>
    <!--Other Views...-->
</Grid>
```

I'm using `ColumnSpan="2"` so that I have a width of exactly one column after using `Scale="0.5"`, but this might already be a wrong approach and I would definitely prefer to not do it this way. Also tried changing the `HeightRequest` to 120 after the scaling happens, but this will also shorten the height of `MyCustomView`.

What is the optimal approach to fill a Grid Cell with a scaled down View?

---

### Sample Repository:

https://github.com/Zure1/ScaleSample/

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this, but, in the 3rd row, you just want for the view to occupy the second column?

Comment: Also (unrelated), how did you achieve that nice frame view with the border in the left?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Yes, I want to achieve what's shown in the first image. I achieved the rounded corners with custom effects for Android/iOS (notice that it's rounded on the right side of the Views too, not only the left side). If you want only one side rounded, you have to lay another `Frame` over your actual View to cover the rounded corners on one side :)

Comment: Can you share the xaml code? No need all code but the relevant code.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT added code

Comment: For the first problem, do you mean the Meine tour view overlay the circle view? Why is the Meine tour view in the center? Can you please add more code about the Grid? For the second problem, how did you specify the height of Grid.row? Your code is not enough to reproduce the problem. And why you use a  a scaled down View?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes that's the problem, it should look like in the first image where MyCustomView is on the right side, filling the 2nd column. I added code, if you want I can create a repo with some easier controls like Labels to reproduce my problem. I'm using scale because I want to display a view which is scaled down to 0.5 at this grid cell. It's a preview of another page and on click, I'm navigating to this page which shows MyCustomView in full scale.

Comment: If you can provide a repo to reproduce the problem, it is easier for us to find out the problem. And some easier controls like Labels is enough.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Added a sample repo to my question. I also changed the layout a bit to show better what I want to achieve. Also it's clearer with Labels that it's the expected outcome of how `Scale` actually works, but this doesn't change my original question about how I can fill a cell with a scaled down view.

Comment: What will happen if you remove the `Scale="0.5"` of the grid and put the customView directly in to the Grid? If you give a scale to Grid, it wont fill the cell as it is scaled down.

Comment: I still confused about what you want to achieve in this question. In you demo, you scaled the Gird and the label inside the Grid did fill the scaled Grid cell. While what you expected is the label fill the whole cell(the size without scaling), so what's the purpose of setting the scale?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194477/discussion-between-dennis-schroer-and-jack-hua-msft).

Answer (score 0):

I did some test and can't a way to fill a `Grid Cell` with a scaled down View.

You can open a free Xamarin support case here: [supportforXamarin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6) to get more help and find if there is any solution to it.

Instead of use a `scaled down` View, I use a View with `grid layout` to achieve the similar requirement as yours and I upload a sample(based on you) here: [resizeView-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/resizeView-xamarin.forms). You can have a look at it and maybe you can find some idea from it. Hope it make sense to you.